# An error I encountered while getting a json file

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-mvc

I need to pull a json file on the remote server.I leave the link of the file here.
turkmedya.com.tr/anasayfa.json

I also share the open version of the json file as a photo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRwvZ.jpg)

I also have to pull the categories from the file. Can you give me a hand?

```
Anasayfa.cs

 public class data
    {
        public string sectionType { get; set; }
        public string titleBgColor { get; set; }
        public IList<veri> itemList { get; set; }
      
    }
    public class veri
    {
        public string shortText { get; set; }
        public string fullPath { get; set; }
        public string itemId { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class cat
    {
        public string categoryId { get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
    }
    public class ListJson
    {
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        public IList<data> data { get; set; }
        public IList<cat> category { get; set; }
    }

HomeController.cs
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string url = @"http://turkmedya.com.tr/anasayfa.json";
            string jsonVerisi = "";
            try
            {
                using (WebClient response = new WebClient())
                {
                    jsonVerisi = response.DownloadString(url);
                }
                ListJson account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListJson>(jsonVerisi);

                foreach (var list in account.data)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(list.ToString());
                    ViewBag.ca = list.itemList.ToList();
                    var a = account.data.Count;
                    var b = list.itemList.Count;
                }

              
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            return View();

        }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error :) I can pull the data up to the itemlist in the json file. But I have to shoot the categories in the itemlist. I couldn't do it there.

Comment: Your title says you got an error. I suggest you change the title.